# Flash AS3 interactive iPhone

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, flash, interactive

For a university project I am trying to produce a semi-interactive iphone. 
I am stuck on the messaging app though, using AS3 does anyone know how I would be able to enable the user to send a message, and this message then appear in the sent box? Basically the message needs to be stored and then shown again in sent messages with the contact name and the message? I think it has something to do with the storage variable but not entirely sure!

Any help would be really appreciated!!
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use xml to store it, and to get it back.
To write it onto the box an input text or a dynamic text could help you.

Comment: Thanks, i have the input texts already on there. Not very sure about how XML works so might have to give it a miss :/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is using SharedObjects.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html